# How to get the name of a unique constraint in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

I need to drop a unique constraint from a postgresql table, but I didn't give it a name in the schema. Does anybody know, how to get the name of such a constraint, or how to drop it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

That is something like (for single column constaint):

```
tableName_columnName_key
```

To get constaint name write (in psql):

```
\d tableName
```

or use [`pg_constraint`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) system catalog:

```
SELECT conname
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conrelid =
    (SELECT oid 
    FROM pg_class
    WHERE relname LIKE 'tableName');
```

Also you can get it from pgAdmin in objects tree.

Comment: Thank you, it helped, but when I dropped the constraint with alter, it also dropped the index. Don't you know why?

Comment: Unique constraint has its own, implicit and inner btree index (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2445)

Comment: How to filter by the name of the referenced table?

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT conname
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE conrelid = 'mytable'::regclass::oid
```